# Customized setFlash() when delete a post

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm folllowing their basic tutorial for creating a blog. On delete step I have:

```
public function delete($id){
    // if($this -> request -> is('get')){
    //  throw new MethodNotAllowedException(); }

     if ($this -> Post -> delete($id)) {
        $this -> Session -> setFlash(
            __('The article %s was deleted', h($id)));//here is the line
            return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
     }

}
```

I would like instead of `The article ID was deleted` to get `The article TITLE was deleted`;

My question is why the code below don't work in this case?

```
    __('The article %s was deleted', h($title)));
```

Comment: i havnt seen the h declaration anywhere ??

Comment: How do you expect that to work, there is no variable named `title` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @AvinashBabu, isn't declared. The original can be found here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#deleting-posts

Comment: @ndm, do you have any ideea how the title should be declared to work in my function?

Comment: @AvinashBabu h is a global function provided by CakePHP.

Comment: @ADDA you first have to retrieve the respective post with find/findById, the title is then available in the returned array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function delete($id){
     // get the title
     $this->Post->id = $id;
     $title = $this->Post->field('title');

     // delete the record
     if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article %s was deleted', h($title))); // output the title
        return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

since `$id` is passed as an argument to the delete function.

We can directly access it in the following line.

```
 __('The article %s was deleted', h($id)));
```

But for Accessing other field's from the table you have to fetch it from the database

using the passed  `$id`.

Such as :

```
$title = $this->Post->field('title');
```

And then use it.

This is your complete code with modification.

```
public function delete($id){

 $this->Post->id = $id;
 $title = $this->Post->field('title');


 if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The article %s was deleted', h($title))); 
    return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 }
```